# How can I show a list of grandchildren pages related to the child page that i'm on?

Tags: wordpress

I'm on a child page and trying to output a list of that page's child pages. Is that considered grandchildren pages? I guess so relative to the parent page. This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
function wpb_list_grandchild_pages() { 

    global $post;

    // Vars
    $page = get_the_title();
    $id = $post->ID;

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0&depth=2' );
    else
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $id . '&echo=0&depth=2' );
    if ( $childpages ) {
        $html_out = '';

        $html_out .= '<div class="child-page-container child-page-' . $id . '">';
            $html_out .= '<ul class="child-page-list">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
        $html_out .= '</div>'; // child-page-container
    }

    return $html_out;
}

add_shortcode('wpb_grandchildpages', 'wpb_list_grandchild_pages');
```

The `depth` being `1` showed the child pages, making it `2` showed the child pages and grandchildren, but I only want to show the grandchildren relative only to the page that I'm on.

Answer (score 0):

Use the argument 'child_of' and set it to the parent ID.  This will give you the grandchildren of a page that you are on that is a child page.

```
$args = array( 'child_of' => $post->ID );
wp_list_pages( $args );
```